# C# Radar Chart not showing all x axis coordinates and multiple y coordinates

Tags: c#, mschart, radar-chart

I have instantiated a string list with 9 values to be displayed on the spokes of my radar charts but only 5 are being displayed. I have tried setting AxisX.Interval=1 as suggested in some posts but it doesn't help.
Also, The chartarea has 5 series that have to be displayed and I've added them to the ChartArea as well but they do not show up.
Here is the code:

```
string[] xValues = { "Incoming Call Duration", "Outgoing Call Duration", "Package Frequency", "Activation Rate", "Creation Source", "Locations", "Incoming Call Frequency", "Outgoing Call Frequency", "Incoming Cell Utilization", "Outgoing Cell Utilization" };

while (myReader.Read())
{
    yValues_base.Add(myReader.GetDecimal(0));
    yValues_cluster1.Add(myReader.GetDecimal(1));
    yValues_cluster2.Add(myReader.GetDecimal(2));
    yValues_cluster3.Add(myReader.GetDecimal(3));
    yValues_cluster4.Add(myReader.GetDecimal(4));

}

yValues_base.ToArray();
yValues_cluster1.ToArray();
yValues_cluster2.ToArray();
yValues_cluster3.ToArray();
yValues_cluster4.ToArray();

radar_chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
radar_chart.Size = new Size(2000, 2000);

radar_chart.Series["Reference Data"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues_base);
radar_chart.Series["Cluster 1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues_cluster1);
radar_chart.Series["Cluster 2"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues_cluster2);
radar_chart.Series["Cluster 3"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues_cluster3);
radar_chart.Series["Cluster 4"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues_cluster4);
radar_chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
radar_chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

---

What am I doing wrong?